# jQuery JSON Decode ( PHP to Javascript)

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I'm trying to make an autocomplete script. I pass variables through JSON, and then I don't know how to go on to decode JSON.

This is an example of the JSON code I got, and I'd like to convert it in a simple javascript array:

```
[{"ID":"1","name":"Amateur astronomy \r"},{"ID":"2","name":"Amateur microscopy \r"},{"ID":"173","name":"Amateur radio \r"},{"ID":"299","name":"Amateur astronomy \r"},{"ID":"349","name":"Amateur theater \r"}]
```

Comment: what to do if i have special character in json string??

Comment: I know it's been over 2 years, but did you ever figure out how to do this?

Answer (score 27):

The standard JavaScript way to do this would be to use [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse):

```
var myArray = JSON.parse(someJSONString);
```

For compatibility with older browsers that lack a built-in `JSON` object, jQuery has [its own method](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/):

```
var myArray = jQuery.parseJSON(someJSONString);
```

Such method is deprecated as of jQuery/3.0.

Answer (score 18):

The standard way with JavaScript is to use `JSON.parse`:

```
var myObject = JSON.parse( rawJSON );
```

If you're using jQuery with `$.ajax` (*or alternative*) you can use `dataType: 'json'`

```
$.ajax({ 
    type: 'GET', 
    url: 'request.php', 
    data: { variable: 'value' }, 
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) { 
        // you can use data.blah, or if working with multiple rows
        // of data, then you can use $.each()
    }   
});
```

Although, if your server sent back the header `Content-Type: application/json` jQuery would return it like this anyway.

Although the other way with jQuery is using `$.parseJSON(rawJSON);` You don't have to do this if you're using the dataType.

```
var JSONArray = $.parseJSON(rawJSON);
```

Comment: This is my ajax call:

[link](http://pastebin.com/AMxQi1Xg)

But actually doesn't work, console says that JSONArray is null :/

Comment: Since you made the dataType to json you can scrap `var JSONArray = $.parseJSON( data );` as it's already converted. I edited my answer to make more sense for you.