# PHP: How do I can decode a json back into array form in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json, decode

I've an array in my php called as `$tempoHeader`, for example:

#### Example Array $tempoHeader

```
-------
Array
(
   [0] => red
   [1] => green
   [2] => yellow
   [3] => blue
)
```

I want to send it into my external *javascript*, so I do this one in my **php code**:

#### My PHP: header.php

```
$tempoHeader = array_diff_assoc($modelData, $data);
<script type="text/javascript">var header = <?php echo json_encode($tempoHeader); ?>;</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="upload_header.js"></script>
```

In my *javascript*, I've try to `console.log(header);` and I got this in my console

`Array [ "red", "green", "yellow", "blue" ]`

#### My JS: upload_header.js

```
$(window).load(function() {
console.log(header);                    //this work and print out the header json
   var myObject = JSON.parse(header);
   var myArray = jQuery.parseJSON(header);
   console.log(myArray);                   //didn't print out anything
   console.log(myObject);                  //didn't print out anything
});
```

#### How do I can decode this json back as $tempoHeader array form?

**Note**:
I've read this issue [jQuery JSON Decode ( PHP to Javascript)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17768105/jquery-json-decode-php-to-javascript), and I've try the suggestion such as `jQuery.parseJSON(header);`, `JSON.parse(header);` but I got nothing

Answer (score 1):

```
$res = json_decode( $tempoHeader, true );
echo $res->array_name[index];
```

I hope this help

Comment: That returns stdClass/object. Pass true as second argument

Answer (score 0):

`header` already is an array, it is not json / a string and you do not need to parse it.

You send this to javascript:

```
var header = <?php echo json_encode($tempoHeader); ?>;
```

So you already have an array in javascript as you have noticed:

```
Array [ "red", "green", "yellow", "blue" ]
```

And then you try to parse that as json:

```
var myObject = JSON.parse(header);
```

That is not possible nor is it necessary: json is a string and `JSON.parse()` expects a string as its parameter. You cannot use it on an array.

To use your variable, you can simply use `header[0]` (red), etc. or loop over it like you do with any other javascript array.

Comment: Yah, you're right. My var `header` is already as an array :) thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

The Problem here is that when you executes your JavaScript, your PHP Script was already executed, to "send a variable back to php" you have to create a new Request.

Mostly it is done via Ajax OR you can add your Array in a hidden input field and "send" it with a form.

So you upload_header.js would look like

```
   $(function () {

        $.ajax('update_header.php', {
            method: 'POST',
            data: {
                'header': JSON.stringify(header)
            }
        })
    });
```

and in your "update_header.php" you would recieve the new header with

```
$newHeader = json_decode($_POST['header'],true);
```

hope this helps;)