# It is necessary to make import json in html

Tags: html, json, slack

please help me. How import json message to html

https://slack.com/api/channels.history?token=xoxp-60475805059-60530043287-306411842247-c6e3bf60bc947e3da7250883dcfdc54a&channel=C538LFAQK&count=1&pretty=1

Answer (score 1):

If it is a ajax call you need to call using the jquery, you need to call using the `<object>.<attribute>` like man.name.

IF you want to call using php, you need to decode json array using `json_decode($jsonArray)`. The function is to convert json to array. 
you can call using `$object[attribute]`.

JSON  decode using php: [How do I extract data from JSON with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29308898/how-do-i-extract-data-from-json-with-php#answer-29308899)

JSON decode using jquery: [jQuery JSON Decode ( PHP to Javascript)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17768105/jquery-json-decode-php-to-javascript?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa#)